# StoreKit not responding

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I was following the Kilo Loco tutorial for store kit but I can't seem to purchase the product when its is called. This is my class:

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

enum GameProducts: String {
case removeAds = "BundleID" // I have registered one but Id rather keep it private
}

class GameIAP: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

static let shared = GameIAP()
var products = [SKProduct]()
let myQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()

override init() {
}

func getProduct() {
    let products: Set = [GameProducts.removeAds.rawValue]
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: products)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
    myQueue.add(self)
}

func purchase(product: GameProducts) {
    guard let theProduct = products.filter({ $0.productIdentifier == product.rawValue}).first else
    { return }
    let payment = SKPayment(product: theProduct)
    myQueue.add(payment)
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    products = response.products
}

func restore() {
    myQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "payment"), object: nil)
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        print(transaction.transactionState.currentStatus(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchased: complete(transaction: transaction)
        default: break
        }
    }
}
}
extension SKPaymentTransactionState {
func currentStatus() -> String {
    switch self {
    case .deferred: return "Deferred"
    case .failed: return "Failed"
    case .purchased: return "Purchased"
    case .purchasing: return "Purchasing"
    case .restored: return "Restored"
    }
}
}
```

When the ViewController loads it calls getProduct() and then when I hit a button it calls the purchase function but this doesn't seem to work??
The restore function works absolutely fine but the purchase doesn't return anything...
Has anyone done this before and know where I've gone wrong or is this something on app store connect???

Comment: Do you successfully retrieve the product? Have you used the debugger to step through your code and confirm that transaction is actually sent?

Comment: @Paulw11 I added a for product in products loop after products = response.products and got no response with a print(products)